# why getServerSideProps returns undefined

Tags: next.js

Below is the component

```
function AsideLeft({initialAsideLeftHandler}: InferGetServerSidePropsType<typeof getServerSideProps>) {
  console.log(initialAsideLeftHandler)
  // ...
}
```

Below does not work and returns undefined

```
export const getServerSideProps:GetServerSideProps = async ({req}) => {
  const cookies = parseCookies(req);

  return {
    props: {
      initialAsideLeftHandler: cookies.asideLeftHandler
    }
  };
}

export default AsideLeft;
```

So I tried changing the return value to hardcoded object to see what would happen...but still, it returns undefined

```
export const getServerSideProps:GetServerSideProps = async () => {

  return {
    props: {
      initialAsideLeftHandler: {x:0,y:0}
    }
  };
}

export default AsideLeft;
```

Comment: is `AsideLeft` a page or a component?

Comment: It's a component, thanks! Never knew they are limited to pages only